# Implementing an IObservable to compute digits of Pi

Tags: asynchronous, system.reactive, pi

This is an academic exercise, I'm new to Reactive Extensions and trying to get my head around the technology. I set myself a goal of making an IObservable that returns successive digits of Pi (I happen to be really interested in Pi right at the moment for unrelated reasons). Reactive Extensions contains operators for making observables, the guidance they give is that you should "almost never need to create your own IObsevable". But I can't see how I can do this with the ready-made operators and methods. Let me elucidate a bit more.

I was planning to use [an algorithm](http://www.boyet.com/Articles/PiCalculator.html) that would involve the expansion of a Taylor series for Arctan. To get the next digit of Pi, I'd expand a few more terms in the series.

So I need the series expansion going on asynchronously, occasionally throwing out the next computed digit to the IObserver. I obviosly don't want to restart the computation from scratch for each new digit.

Is there a way to implement this behaviour using RX's built-in operators, or am I going to have to code an IObservable from scratch? What strategy suggests itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to create an `Enumerable` and then convert it:

```
IEnumerable<int> Pi()
{
    // algorithm here
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Usage (for a cold observable, that is every new 'subscription' starts creating Pi from scratch):

```
var cold = Pi().ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
cold.Take(5).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

If you want to make it `hot` (everyone shares the same underlying calculation), you can just do this:

```
var hot = cold.Publish().RefCount();
```

Which will start the calculation after the first subscriber, and stop it when they all disconnect. Here's a simple test:

```
hot.Subscribe(p => Console.WriteLine("hot1: " + p));
Thread.Sleep(5);    
hot.Subscribe(p => Console.WriteLine("hot2: " + p));
```

Which should show `hot1` printing only for a little while, then `hot2` joining in after a short wait but printing the same numbers. If this was done with `cold`, the two subscriptions would each start from 0.

Comment: Right, right, OK. I'm not sure I understand why this is better than the Subject approach described elsewhere. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Instead of calling `resultStream.OnNext(i);` call `yield return i;` - there's not much more to it than that. You're just leveraging the fact that `Enumerable` and `Observable` are two sides of the same coin. Pi is easier to calculate as an enumerable, so we do that, and then convert to an observable. You can completely ignore the rest of the stuff about hot and cold if it doesn't make a difference to you. Just take the first method, and the line `Pi().ToObservable(Scheduler.ThreadPool)` will give you an observable running on the thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, the simplest method would be to use a [Subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Subject is both an IObservable and IObserver, which sounds a bit strange but it allows you to use them like this:

```
class PiCalculator
{
    private readonly Subject<int> resultStream = new Subject<int>();

    public IObservable<int> ResultStream
    {
        get { return resultStream; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Whatever the algorithm actually is
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            resultStream.OnNext(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So inside your algorithm, you just call `OnNext` on the subject whenever you want to produce the next value.

Then to use it, you just need something like:

```
var piCalculator = new PiCalculator();
piCalculator.ResultStream.Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine((n)));
piCalculator.Start();
```

Comment: +1 Ohhhh, yes, that seems quite straightforward. I'll give that a go.

Comment: This is pretty bad practice (calling 'Start') as it breaks the observable model by going outside well known Rx practices (hot and cold observables being different, and `IConnectableObservable` being available with a `Connect` method).